# Склонение названий компаний и организаций

Tags: склонение

Добрый день! 
Необходима помощь эксперта.
Предложение:

ЕЖСФ аккредитован Департаментом 
городского имущества  Москвы и является 
официальным партнером Казенного 
предприятия г. Москвы «Агентство по 
реализации жилищных займов и субсидий»

Вопрос: необходимо ли склонять в этом предложении слово "Агентство" (агентства)?
        Если да, то согласно каким правилам.

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все названия в кавычках являются несогласованным приложением и не склоняются